# jQuery DataTables filtering cell data that is an array

Tags: jquery, datatables

My table is rendering correctly, but I am struggling how to filter the values for a specific column/row.

Here is the column definition:

```
{
    'aTargets': [9],
    'bSortable': true,
    'bVisible': true,
    'mData': 'partlist',
    'mRender': function(data, type, row) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if ($.inArray(val.name, partArray) === -1) {
                partArray.push(val.name);
             }
         });
         return partArray;
     }
 }
```

This is working great. In my table, I get an array of part numbers that resembles something like:

```
[123,456,789...]
```

I have a drop-down that also contains a list of part numbers. When a user chooses any given part number, I want to filter the rows that contain that part number. Granted, other numbers will be in the row, I am only interested that the row contains the selected part number.

Here is my current filter setup:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if ($('#showHideByPartNumber').val() === "" || $('#showHideByPartNumber').val() === 'undefined')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
         console.log(typeof (aData[9])); // Returns Object
         console.log(aData[9]); // Returns ["123", "456", "789", "987", "654", "321"]
                                //         ["123", "456", "789", "987", "654", "321"]
                                //         ["123", "456", "789", "987", "654", "321"]
     }
```

}
);

I am getting ALL part numbers from aData for each row. Let's say I have 3 rows, I will get:

```
    [123, 456, 789, 987, 654, 321]
    [123, 456, 789, 987, 654, 321]
    [123, 456, 789, 987, 654, 321]
```

This means the filtering will return a match for each row. 
In reality, I am trying to step into the results of aData something like:

```
    [123, 456]
    [789]
    [987,654,321]
```

(Which is what my table is correctly showing) so that I can correctly filter the row(s).

Thank you for any suggestions I appreciate your time.

Comment: If you can post a working example on jsFiddle or something similar I might be able to suggest something, but I can't really tell what's happening from what you have posted.

Comment: Yes, I should have done that to begin with.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damonjentree/kLSSL/158/)

For some reason, it looks like the numbers are looping too many times. Looks like it might be a glitch from jsfiddle. Either way, it doesn't do that in real-life. However if you check the console, you will see what I'm getting back.

Comment: [**Use this answer ya 'doofis.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151897/splitting-up-array-object-to-filter-values) Shows how to use array values in the table cell